# Bash script in for get \n in the variable

Tags: bash

googling about ways to monitoring some features of MongoDB I found a script to check the status of replicaSet in MongoDB. Script done in bash.

```
last_oplog_date=`/usr/local/bin/mongo --eval "db.printReplicationInfo()" | grep 'oplog last event time' | awk 'BEGIN { FS = "time:" } ; { print $2 }'`
last_oplog_timestamp=`date -j -f ' %a %b %d %Y %H:%M:%S %Z%z (%Z)' "$last_oplog_date" +%s`
lag=0
IFS="
"
for slave_replication_date in `/usr/local/bin/mongo --eval "db.printSlaveReplicationInfo()" | grep 'syncedTo' | awk 'BEGIN { FS = "syncedTo:" } ; { print $2 }'`
do
  slave_replication_timestamp=`date -j -f ' %a %b %d %Y %H:%M:%S %Z%z (%Z)' "$slave_replication_date" +%s`
  lag_seconds=`expr $last_oplog_timestamp - $slave_replication_timestamp`
  if [ $lag_seconds -gt $lag ]; then
    lag=$lag_seconds
  fi
done
exit $lag
```

The author of this code already warns if was written in FreeBSD. I'm trying to execute it in Linux and something weird happen. Firs of all, I changed the way he modify the data with

```
date -d "$var" "+%s"
```

The first part of the script is empty of loops. So he gets the date of oplog of MongoDB and turn into timestamp. Also works for me but...in the second part, he does a for loop to get some info and then convert it in the same way. Here is where is crashing to me.

```
date: invalid date « Tue May 10 2016 13:49:31 GMT+0200 (CEST)\n Tue May 10 2016 13:49:31 GMT+0200 (CEST)»
```

Did you notice about the \n that script is attaching to the end of firs date? I've tried to remove it with tr -d '\n' but also didn't work.

So I cannot get into the last part of the script because \n is stopping me at this point with the error of "invalid date"

I know if something very easy to fix but..I've spent some hours trying to fix it without success. Little bit frustrated.

**UPDATE1:**

I tried to avoid the loop but still no success. If I run the mongo command just in bash I get two data:

```
/usr/bin/mongo --eval "db.printSlaveReplicationInfo()" | grep 'syncedTo' | awk 'BEGIN { FS = "syncedTo:" } ; { print $2 }'`

Output:
 Tue May 10 2016 13:49:31 GMT+0200 (CEST)
 Tue May 10 2016 13:49:31 GMT+0200 (CEST)
```

Then I tried into the script and manage to get inside an array of elements escaping \n

```
IFS='\n' read -r -a array <<< "$var1"

echo "${array[0]}"
echo "${array[1]}"

 Tue May 10 2016 13:49:31 GMT+0200 (CEST)
```

The last array don't show anything :(

Thanks!

Comment: Can you edit this question to provide a full reproducer, without needing to follow any links / include any code not included in the question (or any code not related to the immediate issue at hand)? See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Your date will not be more valid without the `\n`.

Comment: I guess the code after `in` in the `for` loop prints several lines which are glued together by means of CR characters and saved as just one line in the `slave_replication_date` loop variable. In other words, the `invalid date` error message is correct.

Comment: Any idea of how to fix it? Other approach?

Comment: Read [Bash FAQ 001](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001).

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to fix it.

```
IFS=""

var1=`/usr/bin/mongo --eval "db.printSlaveReplicationInfo()" | grep 'syncedTo' | awk 'BEGIN { FS = "syncedTo:" } ; { print $2 }'`

oldIFS="$IFS"
IFS='
'
IFS=${IFS:0:1} # this is useful to format your code with tabs
lines=( $var1 )
IFS="$oldIFS"
for slave_replication_date in "${lines[@]}"
    do
        slave_replication_timestamp=`date -d "$slave_replication_date" "+%s"`
        lag_seconds=`expr $last_oplog_timestamp - $slave_replication_timestamp`

         if [ $lag_seconds -gt $lag ]; then
                lag=$lag_seconds
                exit 1
         fi
done
```

Hope it helps someone with same issue.

Thanks